# Creating an .exe file of a python application with bpy module

Tags: python, windows, installation

when I create an executable of below python application which has bpy (python API for Blender) with pyinstaller on windows platform, The .exe file does'nt run. But the same program runs from Eclipse IDE.

```
import bpy

def test_bpy():
    blend_file_path = "Square.blend"
    blend_out_path = "Altered_square.blend"
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath = blend_file_path)   
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location = (0, 4, 0))  
    bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath = blend_out_path, check_existing=True, filter_blender=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_bpy()
```

The errors thrown are:

[image: command prompt output]

and also this

[image: program stopped working]

Comment: When you build blender as a module, you get bpy.so as well as a folder that contains many python scripts, maybe this folder does not get copied over. For example `site-packages/2.79/datafiles/locale/...` and `site-packages/2.79/scripts/modules/...` While you could leave out the addons folder, the modules and startup folders would be needed.